# Air pressure and convection currents

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, convection

> Air pressure decreases with increasing altitude. So why is
>   air near the surface not continuously drawn upward toward the
>   lower-pressure regions above?

Does this have anything to do with convection currents? Or how pressure variates with temperature across the atmosphere?

I'm not being able to explain this on basis of the barometric equation alone.

Comment: Where did you find this cited question?

Comment: University Physics, Young and Freedman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, let's just think of a perfectly spherical planet with a uniform gravitational field and an atmosphere with constant static pressure everywhere at a given altitude.

What would happen if all the air at the surface somehow began to rise? A vacuum would be created at the surface, which is intuitively unsustainable: to fill that vacuum, the same air would just descend again, pushed down by the air above it as a result of gravity. The physical situation is that the air never rises in the first place because the gravity is always "pulling" down on it.

For a realistic Earth, we have differential heating from the sun as well as terrain, oceans, and other surface features that cause atmospheric mixing, but those don't play into the fundamentals of the question as stated.

As an aside, you might just as well ask why the bottom of a rock wall is not continuously drawn upwards towards the rock above it: the entire system is in static equilibrium, with the force exerted by the weight and pressure of the upper rock being balanced by force exerted by the pressure in the lower rock.

Comment: That the gas should not move upward because it creates a vacuum below is not the  reason it is not doing it. After all, the earth is in vacuum and gas exiting  a gas filled space into a nearby vacuum is actually "natural". So there must be a different reason that it stays there at the surface.

Comment: A fair comment; I've made some adjustments.

Answer (score 5):

Each layer of the atmosphere is in static equilibrium, so there are is no motion of air vertically. The barometric equation is derived from this assumption of static equilibrium.

The pressure below is greater than the pressure above, so there is a net force downwards due to pressure. However, the weight of air in the layer also acts downwards. These 3 forces acting on the layer of air are in balance, so the layer does not move :

$$\frac{\text{upward force}}{\text{due to pressure below}}=\frac{\text{downward force}}{\text{due to pressure above}} +\frac{\text{downward force}}{\text{due to weight of layer}}$$

Note that the downward force due to pressure above is also equal to the weight of the air above.

Answer (score 0):

The question obviously relates to the phenomenon of gas pressure equilibration of two gas containers with different pressures after connection leading to gas transport and finally to a constant pressure in the two vessels. This happens because immediately after making the connection there is a pressure difference at the interface so that a net gas flow takes place from the vessel with higher pressure to the vessel with lower pressure until both vessels have the same pressure at the interface. In the atmosphere (in ideal equilibrium)  the static gas pressure varies with height due to the gravitational force on the gas column. At any fictional (horizontal) interface area of this gas column the total force per unit area on this area from below is the same as the force per unit area exerted by the gas column from above so that no net force inducing a gas movement exists.

Consider quantitatively an infinitesimal gas volume in the gas column at location $z$ of height $dz$ and unit area. Then the net hydrostatic pressure force upward on this volume is $$F_{HP}=-p(z+dz)+ p(z) =-(dp/dz) dz$$ due the barometric gas pressure gradient. Additionally the gravitational force downwards on this volume is $$F_G = -dm g=-\rho(z)dz g$$ where $\rho (z) dz$ is the mass of the infinitesimal volume. According to Newton's law, the infinitesimal volume will not move when the sum of all forces on any infinitesimal gas volume at height $z$ is zero: $$F_{HP}-F_G=-(dp/dz) dz-\rho(z)gdz=0$$ (This correspond to the statement made by sammy gerbil above.) From this actually follows the barometric formula. Using the Boyle-Mariotte law $p= c(T)\rho$, it gives the differential equation for the pressure $p(z)$ $$dp/dz=-pg/c$$ which has the solution $$p(z)=p(0)\exp(-\frac{gz}{c(T)})$$ which is the barometric formula.